# Spark/Hadoop can't read root files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to read a file inside a folder that only me (and root) can read/write, through spark, first I start the shell with:

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

then I:

```
val base = sc.textFile("file///mount/bases/FOLDER_LOCKED/folder/folder/file.txt")
base.take(1)
```

And got the following error:

```
2018-02-19 13:40:20,835 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager:
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, mydomain, executor 1): 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file: /mount/bases/FOLDER_LOCKED/folder/folder/file.txt does not exist
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
...
```

I am suspecting that as yarn/hadoop was launched with the user hadoop it can't go further in this folder to get the file. How could I solve this?

OBS: This folder can't be open to other users because it has private data.

EDIT1: This /mount/bases is a network storage, using a cifs connection.

EDIT2: hdfs and yarn was launched with the user `hadoop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hadoop was the user that lauched hdfs and yarn, he is the user that will try to open a file in a job, so it must be authorized to access this folder, fortunely hadoop checks what user is executing the job first to allow the access to a folder/file, so you will not take risks at this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it would have been access related issue with the file, you would have got 'access denied' as an error. In this particular scenario, I think file that you are trying to read is not present at all, or might have some other name[typos]. Just check for the file name.

Comment: if i try `file:///home/another_user` I got "file path does not exist", but this storage that i'm trying to access is in the network through a cifs connection,  I can read the file using scala with the same path, but not with spark/hadoop.